# Cause of GroovyCastException Grails NamedCriteriaProxy and solution

Tags: exception, grails, groovy

This is an example of an error that has been seen in various parts of our code, and seems to be intermittent.

There is a Grails Domain Class as follows

```
class Widget {
    Date futureTime

    static namedQueries = {
        current {
            isNull("futureTime")
        }
    }
}
```

Then have code as follows

```
List widgets = Widget.current.getAll()

for (Widget widget : widgets) {
    // iterate...
}
```

However on the line above  `for (Widget widget : widgets)` getting the following exception:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException:
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
Cannot cast object 'org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.NamedCriteriaProxy@2e04ce84'
with class 'org.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.NamedCriteriaProxy'
to class 'com.company.Widget'
```

This code has not changed, and was working previously.  The error seems to come and go.  Often (but not always) the error is cleared with a clean build.

- What is this error about?
- Is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I believe you need `Widget.current.list()` instead of `Widget.current.getAll()`

Comment: @dmahapatro: I thought that list() and getAll() are identical (with no arguments provided).  Do you know the difference?

Comment: They are identical when applied on a domain class. I am skeptical whether `getAll()` is available in named query. Did you try using `list()`?

Comment: @dmahapatro: I used `list()` and it worked, but the problem (as I mentioned) is that it was existing code and `getAll()` was working before as well - the problem is intermittent.  There are other places in the code that use `domainClass.namedQuery.get()` and `domainClass.namedQuery.findBy...()` successfully.  But every so often the error above shows up.

Comment: Which version of Grails is used?

Comment: @dmahapatro: Grails 3.0.11